# Does not print out the last number for array using for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, printing

The result gives me this but does not print out the last int (200). I add some random numbers in the main method and the by using the for loops it puts them in order. However, it completely ignores the last (greatest) integer, which is 200. How can I fix this?

```
0: 13
1: 21
2: 25
3: 44
4: 50
5: 63
6: 88
7: 99
8: 100
```

Here is the main method where I add random integers.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortedIntList myList = new SortedIntList(10);

        myList.add(100);
        myList.add(50);
        myList.add(200); // Does not print this line
        myList.add(25);
        myList.add(13);
        myList.add(63);
        myList.add(21);
        myList.add(99);
        myList.add(88);
        myList.add(44);
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Here is the for loop method to print all the integers sorted in order from least to greatest. It sets them in order just fine, it just does not add 200 for some reason.

```
  public void add(int value) {
        if (numElements == list.length) {
            System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
        } else {
            if (numElements == 0) {
                list[numElements] = value;
                numElements++;
            } else {
                int oldValue = 0;
                boolean flag = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
                    if (value < list[i] && !flag) {
                        oldValue = list[i];
                        list[i] = value;
                        flag = true;
                        if (numElements + 1 != list.length) {
                            numElements++;
                        }
                    } else if (flag) {
                        int temp = list[i];
                        list[i] = oldValue;
                        oldValue = temp;
                        if (i == list.length - 1) {
                            list[i + 1] = temp;
                            numElements++;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (temp == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (numElements + 1 != list.length) {
                            numElements++;
                        }
                    }
                   else if (i == numElements - 1) {
                        list[numElements] = value;
                        if (numElements + 1 != list.length) {
                            numElements++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what the toString method looks like

```
 public String toString()
    {
        String returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            returnString += i + ": " + list[i] + "\n";
        }

        return returnString;
    }
```

Comment: How does the `toString` of your `SortedIntList` look like, you have an error in there. Or maybe `numElements == list.length` is wrong, unclear what the values involved actually refer to.

Comment: I added the toString in the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a closer look at your `add` implementation and found it is faaar to complicated for what you want to achieve. I

- removed a lot of code
- renamed your `flag` variable
- changed the loop upper limit from `<` to `<=` since your list should grow by one
- changed the last `else if`
- simplified the `numElements++` which should really happen at once place, everything else is / was a big code smell already

to end up with

```
public void add(int value) {
    if (numElements == list.length) {
        System.out.println("Can't add, list is full");
    } else {
        if (numElements == 0) {
            list[numElements] = value;
        } else {
            int oldValue = 0;
            boolean moveUpward = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++) {
                if (value < list[i] && !moveUpward) {
                    oldValue = list[i];
                    list[i] = value;
                    moveUpward = true;
                } else if (moveUpward) {
                    int temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = oldValue;
                    oldValue = temp;
                } else if (i == numElements) {
                    list[i] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        numElements++;
    }
}
```

which now correctly outputs

> 0: 13
> 1: 21
> 2: 25
> 3: 44
> 4: 50
> 5: 63
> 6: 88
> 7: 99
> 8: 100
> 9: 200